# How to sign auto run application in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, code-signing, autorun

I've read the help of eclipse in blackberry development environment about the auto run application that it requires signing.

From where can I get the sign to enable my application to be auto run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read:
[How to make auto start application in blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078654/how-to-make-auto-start-application-in-blackberry/1080441#1080441)
[Blackberry - how to start my own service at phone boot-up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445172/blackberry-how-to-start-my-own-service-at-phone-boot-up)

I don't think you really need to sign application for autorun. 
But if you will need to, read:
[A60 – How and When to Sign](http://na.blackberry.com/developers/resources/A60_How_And_When_To_Sign_V2.pdf)
[Sharing Blackberry signing keys across JDE versions](http://rschilling.wordpress.com/2009/05/11/sharing-blackberry-signing-keys-across-jde-versions/)

Answer (score 0):

Read the following post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640071/blackberry-development-tips-tricks-gotchas/648871#648871) from the thread: "Blackberry Development Tips, Tricks & Gotchas" -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640071/blackberry-development-tips-tricks-gotchas/