# How to code sign for blackberry smartphone application using command prompt?

Tags: java, blackberry, code-signing

I am new for blackberry smartphone application developing,So now i have been running my application in blackberry simulator only using command prompt.After that i have registered in code sign formolities,and i got three files like RRT,RBB,RCR.Now register these three files also, but i dont know what will i do next for that code signing process.with this process i have take the .jad and .cod file in to my blackberry device, it is downloading but throw error like,[Error starting Application name:Module 'Application name' attempts to access a secure API.].please any body help me how to code sign process with clearly?  thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Run following command:

```
java -jar "C:/Program Files/Research In Motion/BlackBerry JDE 6.0.0/bin/SignatureTool.jar" -a -c -p key AppName.cod
```

Replace the JDE bin directory with appropriate one.

Check following links:

> [How and When to Sign](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/How-and-When-to-Sign/ta-p/442779)
>
> [How to sign auto run application in blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594390/how-to-sign-auto-run-application-in-blackberry)

Comment: i have tried this one,but no use again came that same problem.

Comment: You didn't mention it on your question. When you first build your application, take note of the size of the .cod file. Then run the code signing command. If signing is done, the size of the .cod file should increase. Check for that.